# Using another device instead of RC transmitter

Tags: pid, quadcopter

I want to make pc controlled quadrotor. All the tutorials/projects made with rc receiver. I want to use arduino or xbee instead of rc receiver for pc control of quadrotor. How can I do this.

Note: I have arduino, beaglebone, xbee, hc-05, KK2 and multiwii parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to the autopilot is a 50Hz PWM signal with pulse width varying from 1000 µs to 2000 µs (this is with APM, it should be same with KK2).  In case of a RC transmitter this signal is modulated on a 2.4GHz channel and the PWM values are mapped to the output of a potentiometer on the remote.
Now, you can keep an Arduino on your quadrotor with an XBee, and generate the same signal using the 'Servo' library (it also generates a signal of the same frequency).  And on your PC you can write a python script to transmit PWM values through an XBee connected on your serial port.